# How can values be removed time efficiently from a big array while iterating, in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop

I have an array consisting from 100 000 up to 10 millions short strings. I will use for loop to do something with each value if some conditions are true and then this value should be removed from this array. What is the best way to remove the values - 1. to make an array copy and to remove at Index in the copy, 2. to remove values in place by using reverse order in for loop , 3. something else ?

Comment: Here's some [recommended reading](http://importblogkit.com/2016/03/how-to-ask-a-good-stack-overflow-question/) regarding your question...

Comment: Description a bit confusing. Give some example of expected array in/out after each iteration.

Comment: How many values to you plan to remove from the array? All of them? Most of them? A few of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
mySmallerArray = myBigArray.filter(myConditionFunction)
```

For example, here's how to remove from an array of Integers all the negative integers:

```
myPositiveArray = myIntegerArray.filter {$0 >= 0}
```